# ROS and Gazebo: Documentation Soon?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

[Cross-post from here](http://answers.ros.org/question/63089/ros-and-gazebo-documentation-soon/)

Now that ROS and Gazebo are both under the umbrella of OSRF, when will we be getting updates to the ROS.org documentation of gazebo?

[The Gazebo website](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/1.6/install) says "Only install Gazebo from here, and only follow tutorials from this website. Documentation on ros.org for Gazebo is old and not actively maintained." but doesn't provide any basic tutorials like how to subscribe to a message Gazebo generates in ROS. (There are Tutorials for making plugins, but not for basic usage)

It doesn't seem like it helps the community at all to have such a fractured approach to documentation.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2881/ros-and-gazebo:-documentation-soon?/) by [David Lu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/153/david-lu/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 111 on 2013-05-20

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The latest documentation for ROS integration is here: http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials#ROS_Integration (thanks to Dave Coleman for writing it!).

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2013-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [davetcoleman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/134/davetcoleman/) on 2013-07-24**:
Boom! Documentated.